# RecyclerView architecture - onBindViewHolder nested data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i want to show list as per image for that i am using recycler view and showing row its easy .but inside each row i want to showing many rows

say

```
 i have 10 rows  and each row has different row inside 

 so 1 row have 3 rows   where as 2nd have 2 as on

  so what is best way to do this
```

is it possible we can have one more listview inside that row ?
or inside onBindViewHolder i have to manually loop
 and inflate layout

Edit :- 
 when i am trying this is always shuffles

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        View c = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
```

//            ((TextView) c.findViewById(R.id.mis)).setText(data.get(position) + "");

```
        holder.inner.addView(c);
    }
    holder.n.setText(position+"");
    holder.itemView.setTag(position);

}
```

image as follows [image: Details]

Comment: Use ExpandableRecyclerview. Check https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: can we have any default function for same ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use recyclerview inside recycler view just need to maintain separate adapter for that.

Or in this case you can also use expandable list view which will be much easier to use in this case.

Comment: ecyclerview inside recycler view giving scroll isuue

Answer (score 0):

If in your case,  you don't have many rows, you can apply this:

Use NestedScrollview and add 2 RecyclerViews inside of it.

If you have specific number of rows like 2-3, it will be easy to implement.

Add layout_behavior to your RecyclerViews like below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And wrap content for layout height is important.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And last, you should add this, so scroll works only for NestedScrollView

```
myRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

If you have many items use Single RecyclerView with multiple types of viewholders.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private final int TYPE_MAIN = 0;
private final int TYPE_SUB = 1;
private ArrayList<Object> dataSet;

class ViewHolderMain extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

class ViewHolderSub extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(dataSet.get(position) instance of MainRowObject){
         return TYPE_MAIN;
    }else{
         return TYPE_SUB;
    }

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case TYPE_MAIN: return new ViewHolderMain(...);
         case TYPE_SUB: return new ViewHolderSub(...);
         ...
     }
}
}
```

Comment: main row can be any number as well as sub row can be any number

Comment: @andro than do not use this. Sorry, I assumed you have max 2-3 rows each. If you have many rows, more than 10 this structure will disable recycle on your list. It will affect performance. I use this in one of my apps which have specific number of rows like 5.

Comment: oh any other alternative

Comment: @andro Do not use Nested RecyclerView, use 1 RecyclerView with multiple types of ViewHolders. For Example one Type is Main Row, second is SubRow etc.

Comment: smal snippet plesae ?

Comment: @andro updated my answer yesterday. Also you can multiple questions and answers about it. Keywords: "Multiple View Type Recyclerview"

Comment: but i want for position 1 it should give Multiple view

Comment: @andro do not use position, use itemType. And for loop for view inflating in onBindViewHolder is totally wrong. Your logic is wrong. Check examples for MulipleViewType for Recyclerviews

Comment: but as per my understanding  getItemViewType will call for one position only ? or it will call ? like for 1 position can i have both viewtype?

Comment: @andro getItemViewType must be called once per item. You need to fully understand how adapter works on Recyclerview. I will update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: thats y i cant use coz i want my each row have n number of layout

Answer (score 0):

With the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) you can group your items in sections:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    List<String> list;

    public MySection(List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resource for this Section items 
        super(R.layout.section_item);

        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data per row
MySection row1Section = new MySection(data1List);
MySection row2Section = new MySection(data2List);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(row1Section);
sectionAdapter.addSection(row2Section);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```